# How do I switch out one list's objects with another list's object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this database with items, each item has a list of datapoints attached to it.
I want to update the list and here is my approach

```cs
var currentDataPoints = db.CurrentPriceTableModels.Include(x => x.The30DayPoints).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == currentDatabaseItem.ItemId).The30DayPoints;
foreach (var currentDataPoint in currentDataPoints)
{
    currentDataPoint.Ts = ...

    db.Update(currentDataPoint);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that I want to essentially switch out each `currentDataPoint` for each object in this collection of objects
`var dataPointApi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<The30DataPointsModel[]>(itemUrl).ToList();`

I can't do `currentDataPoints = dataPointApi;` because I can't add a list to the database, it will throw an exception. So I need to update each item one by one like in that foreach loop above.
Any idea on how I can access each objects property in `dataPointApi` and assign the value to the `currentDataPoint`properties?

Comment: You want to replace the matching currentDataPoints object with the equivalent dataPointApi  object for all? And non-matching ones remain in the currentDataPoints list as is? Or you just want to replace the entire currentDataPoints with datPointApi regardless of matching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
var currentDataPoints = db.CurrentPriceTableModels.Include(x => x.The30DayPoints).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == currentDatabaseItem.ItemId).The30DayPoints;

currentDataPoints.ForEach(d => d.Ts = ...); // assign here the value you need

db.UpdateRange(currentDataPoint);
db.SaveChanges(); // only once SaveChanges call, which will improve the performace
```